# How do I check that a definition and a key exist in a Python dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to check that the two user's inputs exist in the dict together as a key value pair togehter; for example:

```
dict = {"ABC" : 123, "DEF" : 456}
firstInput= input("Please enter your age: ")
secondInput= input("Please enter your name: ")
```

Then:
If the user's inputs are "ABC" and 123, respectively, or "DEF" and 456, it will return some value and another if not.

Answer (score 0):

I’m tempted not to give a code example, as it seems like this question could be answered with a simple Google search. That being said, something like this:

```
try:
    value = dict[firstInput]
except KeyError:
    value = 'No entry for {}'.format(firstInput)

if value == secondInput:
    # success 
else:
    return 'Entry found but incorrect value supplied'
```